# how to get value in a url to my php file

Tags: php, url

I am creating an URL like this:

`www.mysite.com/xyz.php/0:100003044058740-1:100000657838131-2:100001676304188-3:1075440919-4:100002474721536-5:100003033556875-6:1257699872-7:1257699872-8:100000501703505-9:100000297352382`

from this function in my .php file

```
function finish(){
        var allInputs = $(".gift_user",$("#scrollWrapper"));
        var param = ""; //:

        for(i=0;i < allInputs.length;i++){
            var inEl = $(allInputs[i]);
            var id = inEl.attr("id");
            var val = inEl.val();
            var arr = id.split("_")
            var giftId = arr[2];
            var userId = $.trim(inEl.val());

            if(userId != ""){
                if(param != ""){
                    param = param + "-" ;
                }
                param = param + giftId + ":" + userId ;
            }
        }

        var url = "https://mysite.com/abc.php" + param ;     
         $('#finishButtonContainer').hide();
         $('#processing').show();
        window.location= url;
    }
```

I want to get the value after xyz.php in my file  abc.php where it take me to into an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either manipulate the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value or pass the the value after xyz.php as a queryString

example:

www.mysite.com/xyz.php?0:100003044058740-1:100000657838131-2:100001676304188-3:1075440919-4:100002474721536-5:100003033556875-6:1257699872-7:1257699872-8:100000501703505-9:100000297352382

Comment: There's no query in the OP's version, so it'd have to be PATH_INFO instead.